# Creating new variable in R conditional on other columns within a data frame

Tags: r

I have data frame with two column say "a" and "b" now I want to create another column "c" which will take value 1 if the following condition satisfied:

a>x and within this subset b>y. x and y are arbitrary constant. The condition is somewhat nested. so if a>x returns 25 observation then b>y will search within that 25 observation NOT within entire data frame.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for how to help us help you answer your question.  Also, I don't see how this is nested at all.  What's wrong with `a>x & b>y` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really suspect you could have figured this out had you tried something...

```
R> x <- data.frame(a=1:10,b=10:1)
R> (x$c <- x$a > 3 & x$b > 4)
    a  b     c
1   1 10 FALSE
2   2  9 FALSE
3   3  8 FALSE
4   4  7  TRUE
5   5  6  TRUE
6   6  5  TRUE
7   7  4 FALSE
8   8  3 FALSE
9   9  2 FALSE
10 10  1 FALSE
```

Comment: When you do this are you avoiding R to evaluate `b>y` for the rows where `a>x` is `FALSE`?

Comment: @JoãoDaniel: `x$b > 4` is _evaluated_ for every element in the vector. Run the commands individually to see what they each return (`(xa <- x$a > 3); (xb <- x$b > 4); (xc <- xa & xb)`).  Elements in `xc` are only `TRUE` if the corresponding elements of `xa` and `xb` are both `TRUE`.

Comment: So actually it doesn't do what the questions asks for. The question says "so if a>x returns 25 observation then b>y will search within that 25 observation NOT within entire data frame.", and it doesn't do that, right?

Comment: @JoãoDaniel: you're getting stuck on semantics. Look at my answer. `x$c` is only `TRUE` IFF _both_ conditions are `TRUE`.  It doesn't matter that I evaluated unnecessary elements for `x$b > 4`.

Comment: It's true when they say that sometimes what we view is not what we see. I could only think that the matter was to avoid evaluating all the elements of `b`.

Comment: @JoãoDaniel: that's very true. Now go use your new knowledge to write more efficient code! ;-)